# SQL Server Data Import / Export Wizard Truncation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, wizard

I'm trying to load a large file into a SQL Server table.  I know that two of the columns are > 50 characters wide so on the 'Advanced' tab in the Import/Export Wizard, I specify the width as 115 and 75 respectively.  I then run the rest of the job and get the following error:

[image]

Is there another place I need to let the Wizard know about the change in length?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database. There is a chance that the table was created from your previous unsuccessful wizard run. It is recommended to delete the table and wizard should re-run successfully without warnings.

Comment: This is first time the table is being created.

Comment: Could you please check that? The very warning you received indicates that that the column (and the table) already created.

Answer (score 0):

Try letting the import wizard create the new table for you. Then you can use regular SQL to move it to its permanent table.